# How to Make Column Visible False

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am Using Grid

I want to make The Column Visible False How to Do?

```
 private void BindClients(String Search)
     {

        DBContext dbcontext = new DBContext();
        SqlParameter[] Param = { new SqlParameter("@Search", Search), };
        DataSet ds = dbcontext.GetDataset("Proc_getCompanies ", Param);
        if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                  grdClients.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                grdClients.Columns["CompanyID"].ToString().Visible = false;

            }
            else
                grdClients.DataSource = null;
        }
        else
            grdClients.DataSource = null;
    }
```

Comment: its asp.net Grid  ??

Comment: yes its Asp Grid

Comment: try code suggested , it not necessary to make use of databound event

Comment: Is your gridview having autogenerated columns, or you have defined   columns in markup?

Comment: If you have defined the CompanyID column in your gridview markup, then simply set it to be not visible in markup as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if its asp.net grid than just do this , in your code remove ToString(). and make use of databound event if possible (its optional, if dont work then make use of it)

```
   protected void gridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     int CompanyIDIndex = 0;//index of your column
     this.grdClients.Columns[CompanyIDIndex].Visible = false;
   }
```

or try this

```
 ((DataControlField)gridView.Columns
           .Cast<DataControlField>()
           .Where(fld => (fld.HeaderText == "CompanyID"))
           .SingleOrDefault()).Visible = false;
```

Comment: Its showing error on CompanyId (Ubicode Character cannot convert String into Int)

Comment: showing error on CompanyId (Unicode character and Cannot convert string to Ind)

Comment: @MujibShaikh - make use of index of column instead of header string

Comment: @MujibShaikh - try out both the solution

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
grdClients.Columns["CompanyID"].ToString().Visible = false;
```

does not make a lot of sense.

`.ToString()` turns your column object into a string representation of that. I' not sure exactly what it would produce, but it doesn't really matter: You can't make a string visible / invisible like this, it doesn't have a `Visible` property.

You need to set Visible on the column object itself:

```
grdClients.Columns["CompanyID"].Visible = false;
```

You may also need to DataBind your gridview before you can do this, depending on whether you have manually added columns in your markup, or they are autogenerated based on the data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the Visible property to false in your markup, if the grid columns are not auto-generated. There is no need to write code to make it invisible.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyID" HeaderText="CompanyID" Visible="False" />
```

If, for some reason, you still want to do this in code-behind, then just replace your posted code with following code. You will need to set the variable `companyIdColumnIndex` in code below ( I have assumed it to be 5 but based on your scenario/markup you should set this value).

```
private void BindClients(String Search) {

    DBContext dbcontext = new DBContext();
    SqlParameter[] Param = {
        new SqlParameter("@Search", Search),
    };
    DataSet ds = dbcontext.GetDataset("Proc_getCompanies ", Param);
    if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0) {
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) {
            grdClients.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            grdClients.DataBind();

            //use if code below to hide the column
            if (grdClients.Columns.Count > 0) {
                int companyIdColumnIndex = 5; //set this variable according to your sceanrio
                grdClients.Columns[companyIdColumnIndex].Visible = false;
            }

            //grdClients.Columns["CompanyID"].ToString().Visible = false;

        }
        else grdClients.DataSource = null;
    }
    else grdClients.DataSource = null;
}
```